# How to write assembly in swift

Tags: swift, inline-assembly

is it possible to write assembly in Swift? i was curious about this. Something like this: `__asm__`Thats possible in languages like C. 
And i wasn't able to find anything about this in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't if you want this you can do this  in objective c and expose your objective- c code to Swift with a bridging header.
Objective-C code:

```
inline void assemblyFunc() {
    __asm__(/*Assembly*/);
}
```

More info on bridging: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

[How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

I also asked this question here: [Is it possible to write inline assembly in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246521/is-it-possible-to-write-inline-assembly-in-swift)

Comment: okay I saw that it was already asked indeed, sorry, but I'll just accept your answer because it still helped me.