# Machine language code in objective c

Tags: ios

> How to use machine language in iOS can anyone help me out.

```
 Is it possible in objective c and swift both or not.
```

Answer (score -1):

ObjC: [iOS Assembly Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/37181/ios-assembly-tutorial)

Swift (though not natively): see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246521/is-it-possible-to-write-inline-assembly-in-swift).